# Why can I not call my IBOutlet so that i can make it a Delegate in XCode 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I am trying to make UITableView delegate so I can use its properties in my project. But I cant seem to call my ToDoListTable IBOutlet so that I can make it a Delegate by doing ToDoListTable.delegate = self. I attached an image below showing that XCode doesn't even suggest it. So I'm unsure on what I should be doing.

[image: A Photo Of my Code]

Comment: Why not connect the table view's delegate and dataSource in the storyboard? But if you want to do it in code, you need to do it in `viewDidLoad`, not in some arbitrary place in the class.

Comment: Oh! Haha thank you! I'm quite new to this, but how would I do it in the story board?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give delegate using storyboard then please see attached image.

[image: For StoryBoard please see this image]you have not give `datasource` or `Delegate` in `StoryBord` 
Than 
Write in `ViewDidLoad`

```
tableview.delegate = self

tableview.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give delegates in viewdidload like 
    ToDoListTable.delegate = self
    ToDoListTable.datasource = self

Answer (score 0):

You can do programatically by writing like

```
`toDoListTable.delegate = self` (just write it if you are not able to get the instance of tableview. sometime it's just xcode issue)
```

or else use the storyboard and select the tableview, tap on connection inspector(last one) and add the connection of delegate outlet to Viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet in your **ToDoListViewController**.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ToDoListTable.delegate = self
    ToDoListTable.dataSource = self
}
```

You should assign your delegate in viewDidLoad() method. It is also recommended to use lower camel case to name your IBOutlet for better code practice. Say naming **toDoListTable** is better than **ToDoListTable**.

Answer (score 0):

you need "weak" after: @IBOutlet and before var

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```